# Minimum value of an algebraic expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

What is the minimum value of ($x,y,z$ are positive):
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+6 x y+5 y^2+4 y z}$$

With the values I have tried it does seem to be smallest has been $\frac34$. However, I can't prove it. Please help!

Comment: What means `cyc` bellow sum sign?

Comment: @Ashot Cyclic sum, its a common notation. Do you know what is meant by cyclic sum?

Comment: @Thelugfzhluswcpzflabucheecatne is it an extension of the reimann zeta function, constrained to positive integers?

Answer (score 0):

A full expanding gives

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(36x^5z+29x^4y^2+121x^4z^2+114x^3y^3+6x^4yz-122x^3y^2z-66x^3z^2y-118x^2y^2z^2)\geq0$,

which is obviously true.